# Share PNG image using Intent (it changes image form png to jpeg)

Tags: android, image, android-intent, png, share

I want to make a function which share my images using Intent . Problem is; i have png images and when i share images using Intent, it change the format of image form png to jpeg . for example there is no background (transparent) of my image.png when i call intent to share, it changes image background to black and format to image.jpg.

Here is my code

```
 protected void ShareImage( )
    {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
        sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
        Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image );
        String imgBitmapPath=      MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),imgBitmap,"title",null);
        Uri imageUri=Uri.parse(imgBitmapPath);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share images to.."));
    }
```

Please Help me to share image without changing its format .. Thanks

Comment: Write the `Bitmap` to a file on internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()`), then use `FileProvider` to serve it to the other app.

Comment: Could please edit my code ?

Comment: `when i share images using Intent, it change the format of image form png to jpeg .`. No. Not 'it'. But YOU. And all has nothing to do with sharing as YOU already changed the png to jpg before starting the intent. And do not use an intermediate Bitmap as you will loose transparancy.

Comment: thats right , can you tell me how can i share without change it to png ?

Comment: my image is in drawable folder (image.png) , how can i make a uri for this image to pass  in sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri); ?

Comment: I tried this one .. but on sharing it says "the file format is not supported".


        sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(gridViewImageId[+i])
                + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(gridViewImageId[+i]) + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(gridViewImageId[+i]) );
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share images to.."));

Answer (score 0):

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` always writes a JPEG. See its [implementation](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/providers/MediaProvider/apex/framework/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java;l=2368;drc=1bbbbc180dbbbc5dae39005b7a0e8a360ab12cf6).

You can easily adapt its code to write a PNG instead:

```
private void shareAsPng(Bitmap bitmap, String title)
{
    Long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, now);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, now);
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    try (OutputStream os = cr.openOutputStream(uri)) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, os);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        cr.delete(uri, null, null);
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The compression quality parameter is [documented to be ignored for PNG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat#PNG).
I intentionally omitted `IS_PENDING` because that requires Android 10.

Answer (score -1):

Convert bitmap to Uri

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 99, bytes);

    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

and add your application manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: This compresses to an in-memory PNG and discards it. Then it writes a JPEG. See my answer.